# Psycopg2 Connection Class Attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

The Psycopg2 connection class offers the **str**() magic method which returns some information about the connection such as the host, username, and database name.

How do you get that information from the connection class first hand? The documentation doesn't say how, and inspection.getsourcelines(conn.**str**) errors saying:

```
TypeError: "<connection object at 0xb690aecc; dsn: 'user=testuser password=xxxxxxxxx dbname=testdb', closed: 0>" is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

I understand that Psycopg2 is a module that wraps the libpq library, but does that mean that some connection object attributes are left inaccessible?

Answer (score 4):

In a more up-to-date psycopg2 versions (my was 2.8.5) connection has a field called *info*.
And *info* has these fields:

- backend_pid
- dbname
- dsn_parameters
- error_message
- host
- needs_password
- options
- parameter_status
- password
- port
- protocol_version
- server_version
- socket
- ssl_attribute
- ssl_attribute_names
- ssl_in_use
- status
- transaction_status
- used_password
- user

You can access theme like this:

```
connection.info.dbname
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`dsn`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html) instance attribute:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='cpn')
print conn.dsn
```

Output:

```
dbname=cpn
```

Comment: I was hoping to get something a little more object oriented like conn.dbname or conn.username. It was only a couple lines to parse the output of conn.dsn, but I was looking for something a little more natural. But thank you for the answer.

Comment: @DevinM I think that you should ask it at the [Git repo](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues)

Answer (score 0):

After digging through some resources and picking the brains of some very nice guys in IRC, it seems as though there is no facility within psycopg2 to return the connection information in an object oriented way at this time. The output of conn.dns must be parsed in order to obtain the information. It can easily be done.

```
for i in connection.dsn.split(' '):
        if i.startswith('user'): username = i.split('=')[1]
        if i.startswith('host'): hostname = i.split('=')[1]
        if i.startswith('dbname'): dbname = i.split('=')[1]
```

The for loop is used due to the fact that the string returned by conn.dsn isn't always the same. It can sometimes include a hostname if a TCP connection is used, omit the host if a UNIX socket is used instead, or have additional information such as SSL or SSH tunnel information. In either case, this is a simple and quick way to parse the string.

Comment: Spaces are legal in Postgresql double quoted identifiers. So the connection parameters can contain spaces like in `user='The User'`